# Why 4 spaces are used as the unit of indentation in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

[Java code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-indentation.html#262) says:

> Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation.

But it doesn't have any explanation as to why spaces are preferred. If I type space 4 times instead of pressing tab just once, I have to do 3 key presses more than just one. That means a lot more work, because coders will write a lot of code in one day. So where does this convention come from, and are there any valid reasons to do more work?

Comment: Don't know, but in Python it's the same. Maybe there's a matter of craft

Comment: In any reasonable code editor, indenting is usually done automatically, so you don't have to press anything at all, except "Enter". It is the first time I hear about 4 spaces, though, always used just 2.

Comment: The cited page (http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc3.html) does not exist any more.

Answer (score 23):

According to some research I found, 6 spaces obscures reading of the code and makes it harder to read. Similar is the case with 0 spaces,

4 spaces is said to be optimum for reading clarity and understanding the logical hierarchy of a program at a glance.

Steve McConnell's Code Complete Second Edition chapter on Layout and Style:

> Subjects scored 20 to 30 percent higher on a test
>    of comprehension when programs had a two-to-four-spaces indentation scheme
>    than they did when programs had no indentation at all.The same study found that it was important to neither under-emphasize nor over
>   emphasize a program’s logical structure. The lowest comprehension scores were
>   achieved on programs that were not indented at all. The second lowest were
>   achieved on programs that used six-space indentation. The study concluded that
>   two-to-four-space indentation was optimal. Interestingly, many subjects in the
>   experiment felt that the six-space indentation was easier to use than the smaller
>   indentations, even though their scores were lower. That’s probably because six
>   space indentation looks pleasing. But regardless of how pretty it looks, six-space
>   indentation turns out to be less readable. This is an example of a collision be
>   tween aesthetic appeal and readability.

Comment: " Similar is the case with 2 spaces," - where do you learn it from the article?

Answer (score 7):

You can change your OS setting to have `tab` as 4 spaces. **Better still do it for your IDE, instead.** You might not like the idea of changing the setting on OS level.

Comment: I agree: You shouldn't be hitting the space bar 4 times, but the tab key once - with the tab getting converted to 4 spaces by your editor.

Answer (score 3):

One can argue about it all day long, but in the end it's an arbitrary decision. And having a standard is better than letting the bickering about it continue until the end of times.

And "more typing" is not really a valid argument against it as you can easily set up any sane code editing tool to insert 4 spaces when you press tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's mainly because it is not fixed how many spaces are in a tab stop. This makes the code more portable as in not prone to display errors just because tabs are displayed differently.

The thing with Java is that you're probably going to end up using an IDE anyway, which makes it obsolete to hit the space key three times.